# Issue with local php fopen scripts returning 404 on CentOS

Tags: php, firewall, openssl

I'm having some trouble today with php scripts running on our server which use `file_get_contents` or similar `fopen` functions. I think this is an openssl or firewall error but I'm quite new to server admin stuff so I need some help debugging it. I was tinkering with `iptables` and `csf firewall` settings and trying to configure sftp using `proftpd` when it suddenly stopped working.

**A simple test:** (this gif file loads fine via the browser)

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.this-domain.com/logo.gif");
//...failed to open stream:HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found...

//However both of the following work absolutely fine:
//a local request to the same file:
echo file_get_contents("/home/user/domains/this-domain.com/private_html/media/logospin.gif");
//an external absolute url:
echo file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/");
```

In php.ini, I have: `allow_url_fopen = on` & `extension=php_openssl.dll` on. Any ideas?

Comment: I get a 404 for that URL as well. And a certificate error...

Comment: Thanks, this-domain.com is not the real domain. I can't disclose the real domain on the public forum unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible this is a DNS issue? I added a 3rd and 4th nameserver as a failsafe today which point to a different web server. I have removed them again now as a test so I'm just waiting for propagation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in fact a DNS issue. `file_get_contents()` was bizarrely routing through our backup nameservers (ns3 & ns4) for some reason, while browsers were routing through the primary nameservers (ns1 & ns2). Unlike the primaries, the backups point to a different server, which does not yet have identical files - hence the unusual 404.

I had set up these backup nameservers only a few hours before tinkering with the firewall etc and by the time they propagated, it looked very much like the ssh commands had taken `file_get_contents()` offline.